# Controlling Fan Speed PWM on Raspberry Pi in Python

Tags: android, python, raspberry-pi, pwm

I am using Android app to control speed of the fan, by using above mentioned code
I am using GPIO 24 with frequency 50Hz
I want to change fan speed when i change it on Android app on run time
I am using sleep function here, fan turns on, on specified speed, but after sleep function executes, it turns off
Any suggestions ?

```
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import psutil


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)

sp= sys.argv[1]
tmp=float(sp)
p = GPIO.PWM(24,50)
p.start(0)

p.ChangeDutyCycle(tmp)
time.sleep(2)
p.stop()
```

Comment: It is NOT so clear what you want to do. In any case, Have you tried to use the statement 'while 1:' in order to continually run a function?

Comment: I tried while 1:
But it then stuck into loop, when i change the value of speed from android app, nothing happens, because it is already been stuck into while 1 loop.
@Leos313